# Mongoose, update values in array inside an object in an array

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

How can i update values in array inside an object in an array.

```json
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("63c7ca9584535c160ee4aaed"),
    "status" : "REJECTED",
    "steps" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("63c7ca9884535c160ee4ab03"),
            "status" : "REJECTED",
            "stepUsers" : [
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("63c7ca9884535c160ee4ab04"),
                    "status" : "REJECTED",
                }
            ]
        },
    ]
}
```

I tried to update using `arrayFilters` but that didn't work. Mongo throw an error `MongoServerError: Found multiple array filters with the same top-level field name steps`

```js
                        Collection.updateOne({
                            _id: id
                        }, {
                            $set: {
                                "steps.$[steps].stepUsers.$[stepUsers].status": 'PENDING',
                            }
                        }, {
                            arrayFilters: [
                                { "steps._id": step._id },
                                { "steps.stepUsers._id": stepUser._id }
                            ]
                        })
```

I need to update `steps.stepUsers.status` in the collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the arrayFilters: `"steps.stepUsers._id"` ->  `"stepUsers._id"`

since arrayFilters is referencing the string inside the `[]`, not the path to it.

```
Collection.updateOne({
  _id: id
},
{
  $set: {
    "steps.$[steps].stepUsers.$[stepUsers].status": "PENDING",
    
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "steps._id": step._id
    },
    {
      "stepUsers._id": stepUser._id
    }
  ]
})
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/V0LV2ksRqbm)

Comment: Thank you it worked. Can you explain why  i am changing to the arrayFilters: "steps.stepUsers._id" ->  "stepUsers._id"

Comment: Updated the answer to explain, I hope it is clear...